# CodeIgniter Returns Uknown Response on IFTTT

Tags: php, codeigniter, ifttt

I am testing the CodeIgniter 3.1 code by making a simple web service.

I found some issue with the response of the API on IFTTT.

The code I have used for the API response in the CI Controller is as below

```
public function setup()
{
        $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
        $header = $this->input->request_headers();
        $IFTTT_Channel_Key = $header["Ifttt-Channel-Key"];
        $IFTTT_Service_Key = $header["Ifttt-Service-Key"];
        if(
              ("xyz" === trim($IFTTT_Channel_Key) ) && 
              ("xyz" === $IFTTT_Service_Key)){                  

              $data = array(
                    "data" => array(
                          "accessToken" => "1224124112411",
                          "samples" => array(
                                "actions" => array(
                                      "turn_on_light" => array(
                                            "device_name" => "my_device"
                                      )
                                )
                          )
                    )
              );
              $ci =& get_instance();
              $this->output->set_status_header(200);
              $ci->output->set_content_type('application/json');
              $ci->output->set_output(json_encode($data));              
              echo json_encode($data);
        }
}
```

The response in the IFTTT Platform :

```
���{"data":{"accessToken":"1224124112411","samples":{"actions":{"turn_on_light":{"device_name":"my_device"}}}}}
```

The Response in the Postman tool :

```
{"data":{"accessToken":"1224124112411","samples":{"actions":{"turn_on_light":{"device_name":"my_device"}}}}}
```

Note: Please don't edit the question without understanding the actual issue. Please

Comment: "some issue with the response" — What issue?

Comment: "When I call the same API from POSTMAN, I am getting a proper response" — The two chunks of code (and I've no idea if they are supposed to represent the request or the response) appear to be identical except for white space.

Comment: "making a simple web service" … "the response of the API on IFTTT" — Is your problem with *making* a web service or *calling* IFTTT's webservice?

Comment: @Quentin have updated my response text, Please check what You have updated. In the response , there where three unknown symbols added before the response string

Comment: By "you" do you mean @Danish Ali? If their edits broke something, edit the question to fix it.

Comment: response is like : ���{"status":200,"message":"success"}

Comment: Quote: "**edit** the question"

Comment: You also need to provide a [mcve]. We can't tell why the code you haven't shown us isn't giving you the result you expect.

Comment: I am very sorry, may be my explanation is not that perfect to understand my problem.

Comment: Correct. I explained what is lacking from it in my previous three comments. Edit the question to fix it.

Comment: In a simple English : 

When I try http://exmaple.com/status api from POSTMAN I got the json response without any issue. 
But, When I try the same API from IFTTT, it shows some junk charecters before the resposne as bleow
���{"status":200,"message":"success"}

Comment: Stop trying to explain in simple English. Stop posting in comments. **Edit the question**. Stop **just** telling us what you get, show us the code (in a [mcve]) which gives you that result.